# Best practice with classes

Tags: php, class, constructor

'I have a question about the best way to handle class properties.

For ease of explanation, lets say I have a class called company. "Company" has single properties, such as "name", "address" etc. In addition to these single properties, "Company" also has multiple employees, multiple offices, & multiple coffee machines. (Bad example, but the best I could think of).

When initializing a class, I can run a SQL query in the constructor method to retrieve the name, address etc. However, as "Employees", "Offices" and "Coffee Machines" are all stored in separate database tables, and return multiple results, to instantly set those properties I would need to run three more SQL queries.

Is this the best way to go, or is it best practice to create three methods "getEmployees", "getOffices" & "getCoffeeMachines" and run the queries when needed?

Not sure if that is clear or not. Here are two examples. Is it best to do this, thereby calling four SQL queries on initialisation so all the information is instantly available:

```
Class Company
{
    private $name;
    private $address;
    private $employees;
    private $offices;
    private $coffeeMachines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = array();
        $this->offices = array();
        $this->coffeeMachines = array();

        ... SQL to get name and address ...
        $this->name = $rs['name'];
        $this->address = $rs['address'];

        ... SQL to get employees ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->employees[$rs['id']] = $rs['name'];
        }

        ... SQL to get offices ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->offices[$rs['id']] = $rs['office'];
        }

        ... SQL to get coffee machines ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->coffeeMachines[$rs['id']] = $rs['coffeeMachine'];
        }
    }
}
```

Or is it best to do this, only run one SQL query on initialisation and run future queries when needed

```
Class Company
{
    private $name;
    private $address;
    private $employees;
    private $offices;
    private $coffeeMachines;

    public function __construct()
    {
        ... SQL to get name and address ...
        $this->name = $rs['name'];
        $this->address = $rs['address'];
    }

    public function getEmployees()
    {
        ... SQL to get employees ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->employees[$rs['id']] = $rs['name'];
        }
    }

    public function getOffices()
    {
        ... SQL to get offices ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->offices[$rs['id']] = $rs['office'];
        }
    }

    public function getCoffeeMachines()
    {
        ... SQL to get coffee machines ...
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array)
        {
            $this->coffeeMachines[$rs['id']] = $rs['coffeeMachine'];
        }
    }
}
```

For what it is worth, I suspect the latter, but could use other opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a matter of preference and performance.  If you can read the child collections with acceptable startup performance, you could choose to do that. Lazy initialization will load more quickly at the start, but you need to protect against trying to populate the collections multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I think running query when needed is the best method, this will make code more readable and understandable than first method. Modification is also easy in second method.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on your needs.

```
$company = new Company();
$company->addOffice();
$company->getOffices();
```

This code will produce different results on each way. Lazy loading is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

When I face situations like that, I prefer to keep the objects separated. So, I would not have a query selecting data from employees inside company class. I would have a instance of employee and that instance would be defined like that:

company.php

```
<?php
require_once "employee.php";
class company{
    protected $employee;
    protected $company_name;
    protected $company_id;
    function company($id_company,$employee=null){
        if($employee){
            {
                $this->employee = $employee;
            }
            //setting company methods values. Here I have the company query
            //...
        }
    }
    function get_company_employees(){
        if($this->employee){
            return $this->employee->get_employees_by_company_id($this->company_id);
        }else{
            //throw same exception
        }
    }

}
```

employee.php

```
 <?php
class employee{
    //employee class attribs
    function employee($employee_id=null){
        if($employee_id){
            //load data from db to class attribs. Here I have a query to get one employee
        }
    }
    function get_employees_by_company_id($company_id){
        //select employees from db and populate collection to return. Here I have a query to return employees from one company
        return array();
    }
}
```

So, when I need the company with the employees, I would do like this:

```
<?php
    require_once "company.php";
    require_once "employee.php";
    $comp_id = 1; 
    $company = new company($comp_id, new employee);
    print_r($company->get_company_employees());

?>
```

Where are the benefits? Employee has a behaviour greater than retrieve informations to company. It is an entity itself. So, why spread its logic to your code? Keep the logic inside its own class and if other class need it, just use. Note, company has a method to retrieve its employees. But company does not has the logic to get it.

It still can be not load employees if you do not need. Leave make the decision when it will need employee and load it if need it.

Of course, I used your example to lead me through my answer. But this approach can be extended to all your needs.